# Copying a file through network giving different hashfile value

Tags: windows

I am encountering a problem where the hashfile value differs when copying a large 8GB file between the local drive of ServerP1 in Production environment to ServerD1 in DR environment through the network. I have conducted additional tests by copying the file from various servers (ServerP2, ServerP3 and ServerP4) in the production environment to ServerD1, and encountered no problem as the hashfile value remain consistent.

Furthermore, I expanded my testing by copying the file from ServerD1 to ServerP1, ServerP2 ServerP3, and ServerP4.

The hashfile results are as below:

[Source | Destination | Hasfile Status]
ServerP1 | ServerD1 | Different
ServerP2 | ServerD1 | Same
ServerP3 | ServerD1 | Same
ServerP4 | ServerD1 | Same

ServerD1 | ServerP1 | Same
ServerD1 | ServerP2 | Same
ServerD1 | ServerP3 | Different
ServerD1 | ServerP4 | Same

The copying method is using Windows explorer through the use of copy and paste.

Do you have any recommendations on preserving the hashfile value when transferring a file between two distinct servers via network?

Should I opt for xcopy or robocopy, and if so, which switch or parameter should be included in the command line?

Comment: Any method should be fine. 8GB is not large, and modern computers regularly copy terabytes without a single fault. I would start haunting for damaged components - either RAM or a failing disk.

Comment: This smells like failed components or strange middleboxes. A simple copy command (either explorer, shell, whatever) will *never ever* change the content of a file (resulting in different hashes). I have seen "WAN accelerators" and "security boxes" changing data while transfering (removing CRLF or similar), but this is in no way correct. This could be a malware, too.